# Seminorm defined by maximum of sublinear functional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $p$ be a sublinear functional defined in a vector space $X$. I'm trying to prove that the function $q$ defined by:
$$q(x) = \max_{|\alpha|=1}p(\alpha x)$$
is a seminorm. I'm having trouble at proving the homogeneity property though, that is, $q(\lambda x) = |\lambda|q(x)$. It is pretty obvious for $\lambda >0$, but for $\lambda<0$ I'm not sure how to proceed. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $ \lambda <0$ observe that

$$p( \alpha \lambda x)=p((-\alpha)( - \lambda)x)$$

and

$$|-\alpha|=1 \iff |\alpha |=1.$$